# How to limit puppeteer browser memory usage

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I've tried both variants and neither of them works.

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            '--max_old_space_size=1024',
        ],
        headless: true,
    });
```

and

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [
            '--js-flags="--max_old_space_size=1024"',
        ],
        headless: true,
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it gonna work as the max. memory usage that can be set varies between platforms, but about the syntax I am sure you should **use dashes** instead of underscores in `--max-old-space-size` if you try to set it via `--js-flags`:

```js
await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: [ '--js-flags="--max-old-space-size=1024"' ] });
```

Comment: Sure! It was copied from some random site and is evidently wrong.